# Django Form and Database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am working width Django now. But I don't make sense about that.

I want to get id and password from the form and check if the password from form is correct to compare with the password of database.

Following are the my codes.

Please help me.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Doctor(models.Model):
    doctor_id = models.CharField(max_length=16, primary_key=True)
    clinic_id = models.ForeignKey(Clinic)
    doctor_email = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    doctor_password = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    doctor_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modify_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Doctor

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
class Meta:
    model = Doctor
    fields = ('doctor_id', 'doctor_password',)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import LoginForm
from .models import Doctor

@ensure_csrf_cookie
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            _id = form.cleaned_data['doctor_id']
            _password = form.cleaned_data['doctor_password']
            b = Doctor.objects.all().filter(doctor_id=_id)

            if _password is doctor_password:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponse('Authenticated successfully')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Disabled account')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid login')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'apiv1/login.html', {'form': form})
```

login.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles%}

{% block title%}Title{% endblock %}

{% block remoshincss %}/static/css/style.css{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    <div align="center" class="imgtop"><img id="profile-img" class="profile-img-card" src="/static/img/remoshinlogo.png" /></div>
    <div class="card card-container">
        <p id="profile-name" class="profile-name-card"></p>
        <form class="form-signin" action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
             <input type="user" id="userid" name="userid" class="form-control inputUser" placeholder="USER-ID" autofocus>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control inputPassword" placeholder="PASSWORD">
            <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
            <br>
            <div align="center"><button style="width: 200px;" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" type="submit"><font color="#708090">Login</font></button></div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: can you use the authentication system already provided in django?
you could have a django user object for every user and have a `OneToOne` field in your doctor data linking it to a user.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. i don't use authentication system of Django. Because I don't really understand it. Anyway, I have a lot of function to get the value from the database. So, I want to do this as same as other function..

Comment: **Do not do this*". Learn how to use that built in with system, it is not hard. And it will save you from the horrible security issues you are opening yourself up to here.

Comment: Thank you for an advice. I don't understand how can I use authentication system of Django. I have many columns in my user table more than User of Django. Second, I have to write more function in user authentication process such as IP address limitation. And finally, I don't understand how can I mix authentication system width my html and css(design). Can I use the authentication system of Django? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import `check_password`

> from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password

## check password

```
pass_ = check_password(_password, b.doctor_password)
if pass_ is False:
   return HttpResponse('Invalid login')
```

### Code:

```
@ensure_csrf_cookie
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            _id = form.cleaned_data['doctor_id']
            _password = form.cleaned_data['doctor_password']
            docter = Doctor.objects.filter(doctor_id=_id).last()

            if docter is None:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid login') 
            pass_ = check_password(_password, docter.doctor_password)
            if pass_ is False:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid login')
            return HttpResponse('Authenticated successfully')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid login')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'apiv1/login.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Thank you for advice.

I add chack_password function. But I got 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'doctor_password'. I don't understand why this error was occurred.

Comment: you need check docter object is not null before compare password.
docter = Doctor.objects.filter(doctor_id=_id).last()
if docter is None:
      return HttpResponse('Invalid login')

Comment: Thank you for an advice. I tried the above code. But I got "form.is_valid=False". What is going on my code? Is there something wrong  my login.html?